# Web-based urldecode and string replacement

Tags: replace, automation, urldecode

I'm looking for an online tool, where I can paste a string, which is then urldecoded and a given string replacement applied. Is s.th. like that around as web tool?
I'm only seeing sites offering one operation at a time, but none that can do things in a defined workflow chain.